# Unity Simmetry Human Movement

Tags: unity-game-engine, transform, virtual-reality

i have a little problem. I am using HTC Vive in a unity scene and i have another human rigged character in front of me. I want to force him to move like me (only arms obviously). So suppose that i move up the right arm, he must move up the right arm ( i only move an object like a cube and then the IK do the rest). The problem is that if i am in the same direction of the other character it work, but if i turn around (always with the right arm in front of me) he moves the arm, instead of keep the arm in front of him like he should do. I hope that this is clear otherwise i'll bring up some sketches.

Comment: **I hope that this is clear otherwise i'll bring up some sketches.** I guess its time to bring them up

Comment: yeah tomorrow i will explain all better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand clearly, but it seems like you have a problem with origin Y orientation, what you should do is apply

```
otherplayer.transform.rotation.y = htcplayer.transform.rotation.y
```

Is that make sense ?